# Array - Increment checkbox name with multiple values each row

Tags: php, arrays

I want to save multiple reports at one time with different emails.
Below is my code:

```
<tr>
  <td>
     <h4>Select Report</h4>
     <input type = 'checkbox' name = 'reports[]' value = 'daily sales report' /> Daily Sales Report <br />
     <input type = 'checkbox' name = 'reports[]' value = 'department sales report' /> Department Sales Report <br />
     <input type = 'checkbox' name = 'reports[]' value = 'hourly sales report' /> Hourly Sales Report <br />
     <input type = 'checkbox' name = 'reports[]' value = 'hourly sales summary report' /> Hourly Sales Summary Report <br />
     <input type = 'checkbox' name = 'reports[]' value = 'inventory report' /> Inventory Report <br />
  </td>
</tr>
```

It will produce an array below:

```
[reports] => Array
    (
        [0] => daily sales report
        [1] => department sales report
        [2] => hourly sales report
        [3] => hourly sales summary report
        [4] => inventory report
    )
```

My problem is want to create an array of reports after appending another row in the table. I want to produce an array like below:

```
[reports] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => daily sales report
                [1] => department sales report
                [2] => hourly sales report
                [3] => hourly sales summary report
                [4] => inventory report
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => daily sales report
                [1] => department sales report
                [2] => hourly sales report
                [3] => hourly sales summary report
                [4] => inventory report
            )

    )
```

Comment: You just want to clone the array :-/ something like that ? ..

Comment: no, i just want the first array key to increment with the next append of row

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    if(empty($reports)){
        $reports[]=$_POST;
    }else{
        array_push($reports,$_POST);
    }       
}
```